# How to have window's batch file detect when the screensaver is on?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10, windows-screensaver

How to program a batch program to determine if a the screensaver is running or if the user went to sleep, or locked the computer?

In bash in Ubuntu Linux I am using the code: `/gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep "is active"` to determine if screensaver is running.

Note: I am not seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries...

Unless there is a better approach, I am working off of this script to look for processes running.  But I have to find the name of the screensaver process.

```
@echo off
set pn=%1
echo looking for %pn%
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %pn%" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%pn%">NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
    echo Found program running
) else (
    echo NOT FOUND running  
)
```

Comment: Your previous version of this question was closed as "seeking recommendation" because there's (_inexplicably_) no close reason for "request for code."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the screensaver process will vary by which screensaver is running, but it should always end in `.scr`.

```
tasklist | find ".scr" >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
    echo Screensaver is running
) else (
    echo Screensaver is not running
)
```

The default Windows 10 screensavers have the following process names:

```
3D Text - ssText3d.scr
Blank   - scrnsave.scr
Bubbles - Bubbles.scr
Mystify - Mystify.scr
Photos  - PhotoScreensaver.scr
Ribbons - Ribbons.scr
```

---

When the computer is locked, the process `LogonUI.exe` runs.

```
tasklist | find "LogonUI.exe"
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
    echo Computer is locked
) else (
    echo Computer is unlocked
)
```

Comment: ok...I locked the computer.... should this script output screensaver is running ?

Comment: @jdl - If the screensaver runs while the computer is locked and the script is running on a loop (because that snippet only runs once and I don't know how you'd run the script _after_ locking the computer), then it should detect the screensaver.

Comment: it is in the task scheduler and kicks off every minute

Comment: always says Screensaver is not running at every minute... and I am viewing this remotely via SSH

Comment: _Is_ the screensaver running? I know that locking my computer doesn't automatically turn the screen saver on. Try running a `tasklist` and see if there's anything that looks screensaver-y.

Comment: can we detected when the computer is locked?  this is different than linux screensaver... ie you don't necessarily see the screen saver... just that the user was put to sleep

Comment: when i do "TASKLIST /FI "imagename eq *pad*" /svc"  to look for notepad... it won't work.   I need to do TASKLIST /FI "imagename eq note*" /svc.  I have to have the first part of the name than a star to get the list.   I would get this:  INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.

Comment: Don't use `/FI` at all; just `tasklist | find "note"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226425/discussion-between-jdl-and-somethingdark).

Comment: @SomethingDark : `screensaver-y`? As distinct from `screensweet-y`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

```bat
@echo off 

pushd "%__AppDir__%"
title <nul & title ..\%~nx0
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "_Reg_Key=HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop"

:loop
for /f skip^=2tokens^=2* %%i in (
';2^>^&1 reg.exe query "!_Reg_Key!" /v SCRNSAVE.EXE
')do if /i "%%~xj" == ".scr" (set "_scr_svr=%%~nxj") else (
     echo/[ !date! ^| !time:~0,8! ] Screen Saver: Disable " - - - - -!"
     rem./ With ScreenSaver is disabled no status is need && goto:next
    )

for /f skip^=2tokens^=2* %%i in (
';2^>nul reg query "!_Reg_Key!" /v ScreenSaveActive')do if %%j equ 1 (
      2>nul tasklist.exe/svc /fo list|find.exe/i "!_scr_svr!">nul && (
      echo/[ !date! ^| !time:~0,8! ] Screen Saver: Running "!_scr_svr!"
    ) || (
      echo/[ !date! ^| !time:~0,8! ] Screen Saver: Enabled "!_scr_svr!"
      echo/[ !date! ^| !time:~0,8! ] Screen Saver: Stopped "!_scr_svr!")
    )

:next
2>nul tasklist.exe/svc /fo list|find.exe/i "LogonUI.exe" >nul && (
         echo/[ !date! ^| !time:~0,8! ] Work Station: Locked  "!ComputerName!"
    ) || echo/[ !date! ^| !time:~0,8! ] Work Station: Logged  "!ComputerName!"

<con: set "_scr_svr=" & >nul timeout/t 10 /nobreak & goto :Loop
```

---

**1.** Use a **`Reg Query`** to see if the screen saver is currently ***enabled***

```bat
for /f skip^=2tokens^=2* %%i in (
';2^>nul reg query "!_Reg_Key!" /v ScreenSaveActive')do if %%j equ 1 (
```

**2.** If the screen saver is currently ***enabled***, use an additional **`Reg Query`** to obtain and save `The_Name + .Extension`

**3.** Avoid a partial string in **`| find ".scr"`**  and use `find /i "The_Full_File_Name.scr"` for insensitive case and for matches `some_name.scr ≠≠ Some_Name.SCR` and `some_name.scr == Some_Name.SCR`

- **Obs.1** In using **`tasklist`** for the task list with **`|find ".scr"`** any string present in the name that also contains a string **`.str`** (lower case only), this will also be listed whether a screensaver may or may not be running.
- **Obs.2** If the length of the characters in the screen_saver_long_name.scr name (including the extension) is greater than 25, with **`tasklist | find ".src"`**, you will never filter/found this file, because the **`tasklist`** (without any `/flag`)  has only 26 characters length in output (, ending with.)
- **Obs.:3** For list process where some screen saver name like **`Security Screensaver NG.scr`** is running, use **`tasklist /svc /fo list`**

**4.** Use a loop and keep the monitoring perceptible to any changes that may occur at any time within the loop process, constantly querying the registry value.

---

Possible status and outputs:

- Screen Saver enabled and not running, but user logged:

```bat
[ Sun 12/27/2020 | 23:26:17 ] Screen Saver: Enabled "Fliqlo.scr"
[ Sun 12/27/2020 | 23:26:17 ] Screen Saver: Stopped "Fliqlo.scr"
[ Sun 12/27/2020 | 23:26:17 ] Work Station: Logged  "LAME_SLUG"
```

- Screen Saver enabled and running, but work station locked:

```bat
[ Sun 12/27/2020 | 27:09:07 ] Screen Saver: Enabled "Fliqlo.scr"
[ Sun 12/27/2020 | 27:09:07 ] Screen Saver: Running "Fliqlo.scr"
[ Sun 12/27/2020 | 27:09:07 ] Work Station: Locked  "LAME_SLUG"
```

- Screen Saver enabled  not running, but user logged:

```bat
[ Sun 12/27/2020 | 25:26:21 ] Screen Saver: Enabled "Fliqlo.scr"
[ Sun 12/27/2020 | 25:26:21 ] Screen Saver: Running "Fliqlo.scr"
[ Sun 12/27/2020 | 25:26:21 ] Work Station: Logged  "LAME_SLUG"
```

- Screen Saver enabled and not running, work station locked:

```bat
[ Sun 12/27/2020 | 25:15:28 ] Screen Saver: Enabled "Fliqlo.scr"
[ Sun 12/27/2020 | 25:15:28 ] Screen Saver: Stopped "Fliqlo.scr"
[ Sun 12/27/2020 | 25:15:28 ] Work Station: locked  "LAME_SLUG"
```

- Screen Saver disabled `not running`, but user logged:

```bat
[ Sun 12/27/2020 | 22:51:46 ] Screen Saver: Disable " - - - - -"
[ Sun 12/27/2020 | 22:51:46 ] Work Station: Logged  "LAME_SLUG"
```

- Screen Saver disabled `not running`,  but work station locked:

```bat
[ Sun 12/27/2020 | 22:44:11 ] Screen Saver: Disable " - - - - -"
[ Sun 12/27/2020 | 22:44:11 ] Work Station: Locked  "LAME_SLUG"
```

---

- To limit to 10 loops, with 10 intervals/timeout of 10 seconds each

```bat
@echo off 

set/a "_c+=0"
pushd "%__AppDir__%"
title <nul & title ..\%~nx0
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "_Reg_Key=HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop"

:loop
for /f ^skip^=2tokens^=2* %%i in (
';2^>^&1 reg.exe query "!_Reg_Key!" /v SCRNSAVE.EXE
')do if /i "%%~xj" == ".scr" (set "_scr_svr=%%~nxj") else (
     echo/[ !date! ^| !time:~0,8! ] Screen Saver: Disable " - - - - -!"
     rem./ With ScreenSaver is disabled no status is need && goto:next
    )

for /f skip^=2tokens^=2* %%i in (
';2^>nul reg query "!_Reg_Key!" /v ScreenSaveActive')do if %%j equ 1 (
      2>nul tasklist.exe/svc /fo list|find.exe/i "!_scr_svr!">nul && (
      echo/[ !date! ^| !time:~0,8! ] Screen Saver: Running "!_scr_svr!"
    ) || (
      echo/[ !date! ^| !time:~0,8! ] Screen Saver: Enabled "!_scr_svr!"
      echo/[ !date! ^| !time:~0,8! ] Screen Saver: Stopped "!_scr_svr!")
    )

:next
2>nul tasklist.exe/svc /fo list|find.exe/i "LogonUI.exe" >nul && (
         echo/[ !date! ^| !time:~0,8! ] Work Station: Locked  "!ComputerName!"
    ) || echo/[ !date! ^| !time:~0,8! ] Work Station: Logged  "!ComputerName!"

if !_c! leq 9 (
      set /a "_c+=1" && set "_scr_svr=" && >nul timeout/t 10 & goto:Loop
    ) else popd && endlocal && goto:eof
```